# How can I make a function that expects a list of variables behave like a multivariate function?

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

I am trying to convert a user defined function that takes two or more variables into a user defined function that takes a list of variables. However, it seems Mathematica treats variables and variables in a list differently to one another in a way I don't understand.

An example of a user defined function taking `x1` and `x2` that works as intended.

```
fun1[x1_, x2_] := x1 + x2^2
D[fun1[x1, x2], x2]
ContourPlot[fun1[x1, x2] == 10, {x1, -10, 10}, {x2, -10, 10}]
```

Now I want to condense the variables to a list `x`.

```
fun2[x_] := x[[1]] + x[[2]]^2
D[fun2[x], x[[2]]]
ContourPlot[fun2[x] == 10, {x[[1]], -10, 10}, {x[[2]], -10, 10}]
```

The differentiation step on `fun2` outputs the expected `2 x[[2]]` but with warnings `Part::partd: Part specification x[[1]] is longer than depth of object.`, `Part::partd: Part specification x[[2]] is longer than depth of object.`, `Part::partd: Part specification x[[2]] is longer than depth of object.` and `General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.`.

The ContourPlot does not render and outputs warnings `Part::partd: Part specification x[[1]] is longer than depth of object.` and `ContourPlot::itraw: Raw object x[[1]] cannot be used as an iterator.`.

What am I doing incorrectly in specifying a function that takes a list of variables? Are there alternate ways of writing functions that will take a large vector of inputs?

Comment: Except for the last line, you can:
`xs = Array [x, 2];
fun2 [x__]: = x [[1]] + x [[2]] ^ 2
D [fun2 @ xs, xs [[2]]]`

Comment: And maybe you find `xs = Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, 2}];` more attractive... But `ContourPlot` just does not like vector inputs. The closest you can get to it is `ContourPlot[
 fun2[{x, y}] == 10, {x, y} \[Element] 
  Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}]]`.

Comment: Dummy variables in functions like D, ContourPlot should be a plain symbol like 'x1' 'x[[1]]' is in a full form 'Part[x,1]' which is not a plain symbol. You have to use them like this ; `D[fun2[{x1, x2}], x2]
ContourPlot[fun2[{x1, x2}] == 10, {x1, -10, 10}, {x2, -10, 10}]`

Answer (score 3):

You can eliminate your problem by defining your function so that it takes both multiple arguments and a list of arguments.

```
fun[x1_, x2_] := x1 + x2^2
fun[{x1_, x2_}] := fun[x1, x2]
```

Now when you have a list of arguments, you simply give `fun` the list. Like so:

```
D[fun[{x1, x2}], x2]
ContourPlot[fun[{x1, x2}] == 10, {x1, -10, 10}, {x2, -10, 10}]
```

The results are:

> `2 x2`

and

[image: plot]